# What is the idiomatic Twisted way to implement observers?

Tags: python, twisted

I have a class that encapsulates database access by my application, and I want to allow other parts of the application to be notified when rows change in the database. Right now, I'm maintaining a list of callback functions, out of which I just-in-time create a DeferredList when I need to send a notification. This seems super kludgy -- is there a more idiomatic way?

Sample Code:

```
class Db(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.observers = []

  def _on_notify(self, notify):
    # called by the db connection
    DeferredList(*[Deferred().addCallback(observer) for observer in self.observers]).callback(dict(notify=notify, db=self))

  def observe(self, callback):
    self.observers.append(callback)
```

Comment: What do you think this `DeferredList` construct does for you that just calling the functions doesn't?

Comment: It calls them in parallel

Comment: @Silas - No, it does not.